# Nautilus No Window Bar After Upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, nautilus, window

After upgrading today to 14.04 from 12.04, I noticed that Nautilus has no window bar. Other programs has it. Can someone please show me what I needed to do to restore it?

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have been using 14.04 and I have Nautilus window decorator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yoy would need to go back to a previous Gnome release, [client side decorations](http://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2014/01/13/client-side-decorations-continued/) is now how Gnoe Core apps handle window decoration, merging the toolbar with the window controls.